# Not able to transfer unique session values from one page to the another

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have created an application and I want to transfer unique values/id from one page to the another. I have used session for this process.

**Below code:**

```
<?php session_start();?>
   <?php
#php code to get values
include_once "process/config.php";
$sql = "select * from posts";
static $i=0;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
$_SESSION["post_row_id"] = $rows["id"]; #Storing post id for updation.
echo $_SESSION["post_row_id"];
?>         

        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td><?php echo ++$i; ?></td>

    <td><u><a onmouseover="this.style.color='blue'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'" href="post_action.php">
    <?php echo $rows["post_title"]; ?></a></u></td>

        </tr>                                       
  <?php
    }

}
?>
```

I want to transfer row_id to the **post_action.php** page with **$_SESSION["post_row_id"]** but each and every time i click anchor tag the last id is transfered to the next page.
but when i echo **$_SESSION["post_row_id"]** all the unique values are shown.

**Note**:
**I did by passing id in the anchor tag its working fine. but in the URL the value is getting displayed and anyone can change that value and pass some other data. Session's are safe at that point, so I was trying to do it with the session**

Comment: 1. you need to add `session_start();` on each page on top where you are going to deal with `SESSION`

Comment: href="post_action.php?row_id=<?php  echo $rows["id"]; ?>"

Comment: @AlivetoDie: i have already added that line of code.

Comment: @JYoThI: I want to do it with the session variable.

Comment: the session variable is being written inside a loop so it will finally contain the last `post_row_id` value only

Comment: this is because .. the session is being replaced by a new value for each loop ..

Comment: your overwriting $_SESSION["post_row_id"]  variable inside the loop . so need to store it into array like this $_SESSION["post_row_id"][] = $rows["id"];

Comment: @JasshhAndrews Why you need to do this ? Can you tell me about your requirement. so based on that I can tell you the answer

Comment: @AhmedGinani: I did by passing id in the anchor tag its working fine. but in the URL the value is getting displayed and anyone can change that value and pass some other data. Session's are safe at that point. so I was trying to do it with the session.

Comment: you can able to store all id  in session .but you can't find which row is clicked @JasshhAndrews

Comment: @JYoThI: how is this possible $_SESSION["post_row_id"][]. $session is string its not an  array.

Comment: @JasshhAndrews - I think as per your requirement session shouldn't work. What you need to do is either you can use post request or get request. but on submit page you can validate Id for security reason.

Comment: simple use `GET method.` for security purpose validate it on server side . @JasshhAndrews

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you need to pass the current row unique id so use  it like this using `GET method.`  `for security purpose validate it on server side`

```
<a href="post_action.php?row_id=<?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>"<?php echo $rows["post_title"]; ?></a>
```

Note : you can able to store all id in session .but you can't find which row is clicked @JasshhAndrews

Answer (score 0):

```
To stick with your original code,
you can pass parameters on your <a href> tag, 
by adding something like this to your url,

<a href="post_action.php?rows_id=$rows_id"></a>

 if your goal is just to pass that id to another page,  you may remove the session since its no longer needed since the id is already passed on your url,


<?php session_start();?>
           <?php
        #php code to get values
        include_once "process/config.php";
        $sql = "select * from posts";
        static $i=0;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
        $_SESSION["post_row_id"] = $rows["id"]; #Storing post id for updation.
        echo $_SESSION["post_row_id"];
        ?>         

                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td><?php echo ++$i; ?></td>

            <td><u><a onmouseover="this.style.color='blue'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'" href="post_action.php">
            <?php echo $rows["post_title"]; ?></a></u></td>

                </tr>                                       
          <?php
            }

        }
        ?>
```